# Kernel IP forwarding not enabled for ethernet interface on boot

Tags: ip-forwarding, debian-buster

To enable IP forwarding on boot in Debian, you put the following in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

I've done it thousands of times, and it has always worked without issues. But there is this one Debian Buster machine on which forwarding is enabled for all interfaces **except** the ethernet interface. In /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/ I have the following:

```
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Nov  6 08:07 all
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Nov  6 08:07 default
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Nov  6 07:53 enp0s25
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Nov  6 08:07 lo
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Nov  6 08:07 tun-mega
```

The content of all files is 1, except enp0s25, which is 0. So the forwarding does not work until I enable it manually. I've tried to enable it specifically in /etc/sysctl.conf:

```
net.ipv4.conf.enp0s25.forwarding=1
```

But it makes no difference. I notice that the file enp0s25 has a different timestamp, so that may be the key to understanding what is going on.

Comment: Maybe systemd-networkd is enabled on that machine? systemctl status systemd-networkd If so I think you might need to create an additional config file https://linuxhint.com/enable_ip_forwarding_ipv4_debian_linux/

Comment: @HenrikPingel No, systemd-networkd is not enabled, I've checked.

Comment: You could create a service that should start very early (before procps or networking), and would log the output of `ip monitor netconf` which will catch changes like `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.enp0s25.forwarding=0`. `ip monitor` monitors events and thus never ends.

Comment: @A.B Good idea, however not having done something like that before, I ended up rendering the system unbootable. Any pointer on how such service should look like?

Comment: I would think a simple type service that simply starts ip monitor netconf. The information will be in the logs and journal. With StandardOutput=journal (or syslog or ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it is a bug in **ifupdown2** utility, which I was unaware was even installed. Until bug resolution gets into Buster, the workaround is to set ip-forward parameter in /etc/network/interfaces:

```
iface enp0s25 inet static
    address x.x.x.x
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway x.x.x.x
    ip-forward 1
```